# ¿Es lo mismo usar "a dónde" que "adónde"?

Tags: adverbios, preguntas

Leyendo [un artículo](http://blogs.publico.es/vicenc-navarro/2017/03/15/quien-acosa-a-quien-la-desverguenza-de-el-pais/) me topé con el siguiente título de sección:

> ¿**A dónde** va ‘El País’?

Inicialmente pensé que era erróneo y ya buscaba el botón de "editar" para corregirlo por un *adónde* todo junto:

> ¿**Adónde** va ‘El País’?

Pero me entró la duda. Al fin y al cabo, los periódicos tienen correctores y algún motivo tendrían para escribirlo así. Por tanto, ¿es lo mismo usar "a dónde" que "adónde"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sí, es lo mismo usar *adónde* que *a dónde*.

Tal y como explica el RAE en el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas:

> [**adónde**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=wFbvYdpRYD6ESQMlOO).
>
> 1. Adverbio interrogativo o exclamativo que significa ‘a qué lugar’. Es tónico y por ello se escribe con tilde, a diferencia del adverbio relativo adonde (→ adonde). Introduce enunciados interrogativos o exclamativos directos y subordinadas interrogativas o exclamativas indirectas: «¿Y adónde llegaremos?» (Ocampo Cornelia [Arg. 1988]); «¡Adónde vamos a ir a parar, señores!» (Cossa Criado [Arg. 1986]); «No sé adónde ir» (NHerald [EE. UU.] 9.4.97); ¡Mira adónde nos ha llevado tu intransigencia! **No hay razones para censurar la escritura de este adverbio en dos palabras, documentada desde siempre en todo tipo de textos; así pues, son igualmente aceptables las grafías adónde y a dónde**: «Esas seducciones, ¿qué significaban, a dónde conducían?» (Edwards Anfitrión [Chile 1987]); «No sé a dónde queréis llegar los dos» (BVallejo Trampas [Esp. 1994]).

Siguiendo con esta idea, en la entrada del RAE:

> [**adónde**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0o0YuK7)
>   De a<sup>2</sup> y dónde.
>   1. adv. interrog. dónde (‖ a qué lugar). *¿Adónde me llevas?*
>   2. adv. excl. dónde (‖ a qué lugar). *¡Adónde vas con tantas cosas!*

Los ejemplos podrían ser también:

> *¿A dónde me llevas?*
>    *¡A dónde vas con tantas cosas!*

---

Tal y como explica Gustavson en los comentarios:

> Sólo querría acotar que a veces sólo "a dónde" es posible, y esto ocurre cuando es término de preposición en complementos de régimen, por ej.: *El alquiler será acorde a dónde quieras vivir*.

Comment: Bien respondido. Sólo querría acotar que a veces sólo "a dónde" es posible, y esto ocurre cuando es término de preposición en complementos de régimen, por ej.: El alquiler será acorde a dónde quieras vivir.